# Lambda compilation throws "variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Tags: c#, expression-trees, runtime-compilation

When I attempt to compile the lambda shown below, it throws:

variable 'model' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WheelEndCatalogKendo.Models.SapBasicData]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

```
public static GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel> BuildColumnString<TModel>(this GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel> column, WebViewPage<IEnumerable<TModel>> webViewPage, int width) where TModel : class {
    var modelParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<TModel>), "model");
    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TModel>, TModel>> firstItem = (model) => model.FirstOrDefault();
    var member = MemberExpression.Property(firstItem.Body, column.Column.Member);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TModel>, string>>(member, modelParameter);
    var title = webViewPage.Html.DisplayNameFor(lambda).ToHtmlString();
    var header = webViewPage.Html.ShortLabelFor(lambda).ToHtmlString().FixUpNewLinesAsHtml();
    var compiled = lambda.Compile(); //Throws here with "variable '...' of type '...' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"
....
}
```

I see several similar posts; but so far they haven't clued me in to the problem with my code.  It seems like I am supplying the lambda variable (as the 2nd parameter argument).  I have however almost no experience authoring expression trees.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `model` parameter from the `firstItem` expression is not the same as `modelParameter`. In expression trees, parameters are not compared by name, but by reference.

This means that the simplest solution is to reuse the `model` parameter from `firstItem`, instead of creating your own parameter:

```
var modelParameter = firstItem.Parameters.Single();
```

With this modification, your code will work.