# "variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Tags: c#, expression

I am getting this error message for my code: "variable 'assignVal' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

I checked out

- [Lambda compilation throws "variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342842/lambda-compilation-throws-variable-of-type-referenced-from-scope-but)
- [variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556911/variable-of-type-referenced-from-scope-but-it-is-not-defined)

but unfortunately my sample seems way more simple and still doesn't work for some reason.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

namespace ExpressionTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetSyncAddExpression()(5) == 6);
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine(await GetTaskAddExpression()(5) == 6);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Func<int, Task<int>> GetTaskAddExpression()
        {
            var fromResultMethod = typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

            var inParam = Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
            var assignmentValue = Variable(typeof(int), "assignVal");
            var retVal = Variable(typeof(Task<int>));

            var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, Task<int>>>(Block(
                Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
                Assign(retVal, Call(null, fromResultMethod, assignmentValue)),
                retVal
            ), inParam);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break();

            return lambda.Compile();
        }

        private static Func<int, int> GetSyncAddExpression()
        {
            var inParam = Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
            var assignmentValue = Variable(typeof(int), "assignVal");
            var retVal = Variable(typeof(int));

            var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Block(
                Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
                Assign(retVal, assignmentValue),
                retVal
            ), inParam);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break();

            return lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

This code sample seems simple enough that it should be working as is and i'm reusing the expressions, so i don't quite understand why i'm getting this error.

Comment: what line is the error happening on?

Comment: @Claies .Compile calls make the error occur.

Comment: yes, but what line in the code is causing the error to happen?  Your question body says the error is with `variable 'assignVal'` but there isn't a variable by that name in the code you posted.

Comment: @Claies my bad. renamed variables when i added more samples - it's "assignmentValue"

Comment: Unless the async part of this is actually relevant, it would simplify things if you'd remove it. I'd get the sync one working first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't including the variables you want to use in your `Block` call.

If you change this:

```
var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Block(
    Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
    Assign(retVal, assignmentValue),
    retVal
), inParam);
```

To this:

```
var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Block(
    // This is the line I've added
    new[] { assignmentValue, retVal },
    Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
    Assign(retVal, assignmentValue),
    retVal
), inParam);
```

it works fine.

Basically you're using the `Block(params Expression[])` overload, which is only suitable for blocks that have no variables.

Comment: ha! just figured that one out myself. Not gonna forget that one, seeing how obvious it is. The intellisense for those methods got filtered out. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For people hitting this from google ->

This code works for both - Tasks too. Daisy was first to answer though. so give him/her the upvotes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

namespace ExpressionTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetSyncAddExpression()(5) == 6);
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine(await GetTaskAddExpression()(5) == 6);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Func<int, Task<int>> GetTaskAddExpression()
        {
            var fromResultMethod = typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

            var inParam = Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
            var assignmentValue = Variable(typeof(int), "assignVal");
            var retVal = Variable(typeof(Task<int>));

            var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, Task<int>>>(Block(
                new[] { assignmentValue, retVal },
                Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
                Assign(retVal, Call(null, fromResultMethod, assignmentValue)),
                retVal
            ), inParam);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break();

            return lambda.Compile();
        }

        private static Func<int, int> GetSyncAddExpression()
        {
            var inParam = Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
            var assignmentValue = Variable(typeof(int), "assignVal");
            var retVal = Variable(typeof(int));

            var lambda = Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Block(
                new[] {assignmentValue, retVal},
                Assign(assignmentValue, Add(inParam, Constant(1))),
                Assign(retVal, assignmentValue),
                retVal
            ), inParam);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break();

            return lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```